# Binding dynamically within an ng-repeat expression

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

For a TV Guide, I am trying to create a dynamic expression within an ng-repeat directive as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="programme in programmes['{{channel}}-wed-jan-14']" alt="{{channel}}">
```

{{channel}} in my controller should evaluate to something like "eTV". The binding is working fine with the alt="{{channel}}" instance but not with the array instance. Angular simply serves up the line of code commented out. If I hardcode the "eTV" string in place of the {{channel}}, it works fine.

Am I trying to ask Angular to do what it is not designed for, or is it possibly my array handling which is dodgy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, not sure if I just asked a dumb question, but in the absence of responses, I managed to figure out a solution by writing a filter as follows:

Template:

```
<div ng-repeat="programme in programmes | getChannelDay:channel:dayString" alt="{{channel}}">
```

Controller filter:

```
app.filter('getChannelDay', function() {
   return function(programmes, channel, dayString) {
      return programmes[channel + dayString];
   };
});
```

The issue with my initial problem

```
<div ng-repeat="programme in programmes['{{channel}}-wed-jan-14']" alt="{{channel}}">
```

is that I was trying to put {{channel}} inside the expression, but that is the format for markup.

I tried to use the following instead:

```
<div ng-repeat="programme in programmes['channel + daystring']" alt="{{channel}}">
```

but I am doing something wrong here. I am pretty sure there is a way to get this to work - if anyone knows, please comment.